# monacaでiOSへビルド後のアプリでtwitterへの投稿ができない。

Tags: ios, monaca

monacaでjsOAuthを用いてtwitterクライアントのようなアプリケーションを作成しています。

```
    oauth.post(
        'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', 
        {"status":tweet},
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        function(data){
            myApp.alert('twitterへの投稿に失敗しました','お知らせ');
            console.log(data);
        });
```

monacaデバッガー上ではtwitterに投稿することができるのですが、iOS向けにビルドしたアプリをiPhoneにインストールしてもTwitterに投稿されず、「twitterへの投稿に失敗しました」というアラートも表示されません。
ビルド後のアプリでも

```
oauth.getJSON('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json',
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

などgetするときは正常に動いているようです。
どうやったらpost出来るようになるか教えていただければと思います。